# cookies and useragent is not enough ? to emulate browser?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, cookie

I am building kinda a search engine for online shops, and several website are blocking me although I check the robots.txt

Let's take an example, I need to get this page:

`http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Easy-use-Pet-Animal-Dog-Grooming-Nail-Clippers-Scissors-Trimmer-wholesale-Newest/1339057466.html?spm=2114.10010108.0.64.MGPpDO`

According to `http://www.aliexpress.com/robots.txt`:

```
# file: robots.txt,v 1.0 2002/09/23 created by Tsing Kong
# www.alibaba.com
# <URL:http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/exclusion.html#robotstxt>
# Format is:
#       User-agent: <name of spider>
#       Disallow: <nothing> | <path>
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /productdetail/

User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /promotion/
Disallow: /wholesale?

User-agent: baiduspider
Disallow: /promotion/
```

the previous web page URL is allowed and I could set any user agent. But that doesn't work.

Also I've tried the following but without luck:

1. I set a user agent for chrome:

   ```
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
   );
   ```
2. set cookies:

   ```
   curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
       Cookie: NAME1=OPAQUE_STRING1; NAME2=OPAQUE_STRING2ali_apach
   ) );
   ```

   Also I save the cookies for the request in the database, to send it back with the next request.
3. I've changed the IP multiple times. I am using amazon ec2 (elasticbeanstalk) to do so.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a start:

- Websites do not like being spidered and having their resources wasted.
- You are using Amazon which has an absolutely terrible reputation for
  abusive activities.
- You are emulating a browser and being dishonest about who you are.
- You are clearly a bot and not providing a agent name to block access
  via an informational URL within the agent ID.
- You may be accessing the site excessively.
- You are assuming that you have the right to access the site and not
  assuming that you need to behave nicely.

**Expect to be blocked.**

Comment: thank you for your answer, but please note  i have not sent more than 100 request, currently i am just trying.

Comment: what do you mean with amazon has terrible reputation, what does that matter . they cant insert all amazon ips into blacklist

Comment: could you please give an example of, how the user agent should be ?

Comment: @adamkaplan You are using a browser agent when clearly spidering. I can know this on my site within just a handful of accesses. As well, Amazon is the #1 abusive network there is for content scraping. You are not giving any site an opt-out. You are likely hitting the site in a way that is clearly not human. I can go on and on. I have systems that will shut you down automatically very quickly (within just a few seconds) just based upon what I see already.

Comment: @adamkaplan *they cant insert all amazon ips into blacklist* - sure they can! Instantly!! Just do what a search engine does. Pay attention to what successful people do if you want success.

Comment: thank you again,but i swear i did not send more than 100 requests ! please tell me what does the search engine do ?

Comment: @adamkaplan But how quickly did you make those 100 requests? I assume all those requests were for HTML pages only and not for the linked resources?

Comment: @adamkaplan Gentle, slow, honest requests from IP address sources that have good reputations. Make sure your user agent has a URL to a web page that explains who you are and what you are doing. Make sure there is an opt-out agent name that people can use in robots.txt. Doing this, you may get white listed even after being blocked. But you have to give them a chance to know that you are okay. Otherwise, they have no information other than what they see in their log files.

Comment: @adamkaplan For the record, I am not trying to be rude, just absolute about how you would be seen. Also understand that there are several automated anti-bot packages out there plus some hand written. There is a lot of information that gives a bot away very quickly. While I will not give away the process, I will say that honest bots often have the least amount of trouble. Please understand it is possible that you will be blocked or not blocked from site to site. It is just a part of doing business.